# mysql_insert_id() not giving value

Tags: mysql, insert

here is the code that i am using, the code is simply getting the same value by two different methods, but the mysql_insert_id() echo is not giving the output.

The value given by -> echo mysql_insert_id(); is 0

Can anyone tell me the possible reason and how to resolve this problem?

```
include'config.php';        

$query = "SELECT id
          FROM      users
          ORDER BY  id DESC
          LIMIT     1";

if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
{
    $query_result =  mysql_fetch_row($query_run);

    $id = $query_result[0];     

    echo $id;
    echo $lastId = mysql_insert_id().'<br />';  
    //'Query Successful!';

} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Is this like 'last_insert_id'? Its only applicable after an insert. Are you hoping to find the max auto_increment?

Comment: i want to know the id which is last created so yea, which is the max auto_increment. I want to use that id and perform some more actions on the other page

Comment: Just "select max(auto_increment_column)".

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the next auto increment id that will be inserted. I guess you should try this.

```
$query_autoinc="SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mytable'";
$exec_autoinc=mysql_query($query_autoinc);
$row_autoinc=mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_autoinc);
$inserted_id = $row_autoinc['Auto_increment'];
```

Or if you want the last inserted id, you might try this.

```
$query= "SELECT max(id)
         FROM      users
         ORDER BY  id DESC
         LIMIT     1";
```

Comment: +1 Great answer, execpt you don't need the `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` portion. `SELECT MAX(id) FROM users` will do.